# ioslides R markdown footer with image on every page

Tags: javascript, image, r-markdown, footer, ioslides

I would like to include image into every footer in ioslides (R markdown). Here is the best code I found to do it:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('slide:not(.title-slide, .backdrop, .segue)').append('<footer></footer>');    
    $('footer').attr('label', 'My Amazing Footer');

  })
</script>

<style>
  footer:after {
    font-size: 12pt;
    content: attr(label);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 60px;
    line-height: 1.9;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

But it only generates text "My Amazing Footer", while I need to include image. Is it possible to modify the js script here?

Here is the original source:

[gitlink](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/435)